# How to change the field name of Serialzed User Model on frontend in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am making a simple Login/Logout App using REST API in Django DRF. I am using the default `User` model for this behavior.

In the Login API, I wanted to authenticate the user with email, hence I wrote the custom authentication using `ModelBackend`. Everything works fine.

But, I want to change the word `username` to `email` in the front of the Login API. I tried using the `source` attribute, but it does not change. Is there any easy way to do it? I am looking for something like `verbose_name`, that is used in Django Models.

My **`serializers.py`** is:

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='Email')
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        user = authenticate(**data)
        if user and user.is_active:
            return user
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Incorrect Credentials Passed.')
```

Again, I am using the default `User` Model, and I don't want to overwrite/override/extend the `User` Model. I just want to change the name of the field `username` on the frontend to be shown as **email**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a value called `email` and not `username` to your  `ModelBackend` subclass:

```py
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        user = authenticate(**{'email': data['username'], 'password': data['password']})
        if user and user.is_active:
            return user
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Incorrect Credentials Passed.')
```